# Keyboard shortcut for missing imports in Java, VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

So, first off. The Shift + Alt + O does not solve my problem.

In Eclipse I can type like

```
ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then press Ctrl + Shift + O and the import statement is automatically added up top.

I tried finding a similar command for VSCode and thought the Organize Imports would do it, but it doesn't, it just removes unused imports and removes extra lines. It's weird because the quick fix option lets you import if you hover over the redline.

So is there a way to sort of create a keyboard shortcut to import missing files?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O doesnt import new classes, just reformats the input statements. Alt+Enter usually suggests fixes.

Comment: In Eclipse Ctrl+Shift+O does indeed import new classes if you have a statement referring to an unknown type.

Comment: `Alt + Shift + O` is what I use and it is the same behavior as `Ctrl + Shift + O` in STS 4.15, a flavor of Eclipse. You can look at it by using `Ctrl + K - S` (That is, hold Ctrl and then input K, then S. Doesn't need to be super quick) and filter by 'organize'. The one you look for is `editor.action.organizeImports`. It is odd that is not working for you, assuming both of your editors are updated.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I dont know. The ArrayList line is red, I press Alt+Shift+O over and over but it never imports it.

Comment: Well, other than the version of VsCode, I can't really think of anything in particular. I tried with `ArrayList` in the three LTS versions (Just in case they changed something that could not be resolved to a Collection/List) and it worked fine. If anything, I had to wait a bit between JDK changes. I mention the version since some package managers have older versions of VsCode (Manjaro's pacman, for example), but I highly doubt they didn't include such a universal keybinding early.

Comment: @JettoMartínez To clarify, you can write like "Dimension d = new Dimension();" get the red line over "Dimension" press Alt+Shift+O and it imports java.awt.Dimension; automatically? Without any need for hovering over the actual line?

Comment: Yes. It can remove unused imports as well.

Comment: Can you show your operation process? It would be nice to be able to make a GIF or video.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the line then press Ctrl+. then you can choose to add all the imports needed or just java.util.ArrayList. If you just want to add java.util.ArrayList you can press Ctrl+. and . again while you are pressing Ctrl.(If that's what you're asking.)